# Shared drive showing as disconnected but still accessible

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-sharing

I hope this is on-topic for this site :)

I have a Windows 10 PC that gets some network shares from group policy. These are applied at user logon. Currently, we have a network share that uses the J drive letter but it is showing as disconnected in the file explorer (A little red "X").

Using `net use` doesn't show the drive, I can't see a reference for it in the registry and trying to remove the drive, it says that is doesn't exist.

I've found a lot of articles on the web but they are all old and none of them have worked for us. Has anyone else had a similar issue?

Any help is appreciated :-)

Comment: Are you running DropBox on this PC? There's a new issue with DropBox that sounds similar: https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/cbhgt9/what_is_causing_these_red_x_to_show_up_on_my_hard/

Comment: @user1574981 Nope, the PC isn't running DropBox. I have three other computers that are using DropBox though and I've never come across that problem :/

Comment: I experience the same issue. Did you eventually found a solution to your problem?